# Android : How to prevent global data on Application relaunch

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I tried to make global variables by extending Application class.

```
import android.app.Application;

public class GlobalVariable extends Application 
{
      private String myState;

      public String getState()
      {
        return myState;
      }//End method

      public void setState(String s)
      {
        myState = s;
      }//End method
}//End Class
```

This was working perfectly for API level below ICS but it fail if user has set developer setting to keep single activity.

It still working fine if user relaunch application from recent application list but data will be reset if app been relaunched from applications.

Is there any way to have global data for the above condition?

***Edit:** There is a concern about the data security here so I can't store data into any of the storage, internal memory or Shared preference etc. I want data to keep in global variables so that data get lost once complete application destroyed or killed by system itself.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared preferences, and  store data there.  I prefer global singleton createdwith  Application context:

https://github.com/ko5tik/camerawatch/blob/master/src/de/pribluda/android/camerawatch/Configuration.java

( see constructor and get instance )

It uses ( @Inject annotations ) small databinding library:

https://github.com/ko5tik/andject

( no formal release yet,  you will have to compile it yourself )

Comment: I appreciate your reply but storing confidential data into shared preference is not safe for rooted phones. I am trying to user Global variable for storing confidential data.

Comment: it is even less confidential.  there is no way to prevent reverse engineering of youir application. and as you like to store setting  over the  applciation restart, you will have to store it somewhere on the phone ( not safe for rooted phones )  - so you may as well use preferences.